# URL::action not working in jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

Am using laravel 4.2 and trying to update data using ajax but in ajax redirect url not working for me. Because am using URL:action like,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url : "store",
    data: { title: postTitle['post-title']['value'], body: postContent['post-body']['value'] },
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.success === false)
        {
            $('.error').append(data.message);
            $('.error').show();
        } else {
            $('.success').append(data.message);
            $('.success').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = "{{ URL::action('PostsController@index') }}";
            }, 2000);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
        alert('Something went wrong. Please Try again later...');
    }
});
```

i dont know why its not working. please help me.

Comment: note: you need a route to that controller action

Comment: @madalinivascu how to add controller action in route in this situation

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a route in your routes file:

```
Route::post('post', 'PostsController@index');
```

But if you enabled CSRF, then you also need to post the CSRF code. You can do this through add this in your post "data".

```
...
url : "{{ url('store') }}",
Data: data: { title: postTitle['post-title']['value'], body: postContent['post-body']['value'] }, _token: {{ csrf_token() }},
...
```

I hoped this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing here is a really terrible practice. You should never use dynamically created JS code in a real app, if you have a choice.

First of all, you're tight coupling JS and PHP code (kind of anti-MVC). Request time increases. It's harder to maintain the app. You are not able to use prepared (minified) JS etc.

[Why generating JS with PHP is a bad practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript)

Here, you should create URL manually:

```
window.location.href = "/post/something";
```

Just create route and use it without `URL::`

```
Route::post('post/something', 'PostsController@postSomething');
```

Comment: what happens if he wants to change the route for that controller action, what happens with the url then?,why are you calling it a *terrible practice*

Comment: He will go and change URL manually. Updated post tells why is it a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Add a route in your route file:

```
Route::get('post','PostsController@index');
```

change js to:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = "<?php echo URL::action('PostsController@index') ?>";
            }, 2000);
```

or:

```
   setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location = "<?php echo action('PostsController@index') ?>";
                }, 2000);
```

Comment: Its not working, it returns url like `http://localhost/editorlara4/public/posts/%7B%7B%20URL::action%28'PostsController@index'%29%20%7D%7D`

Comment: do you have blade enabled on the template?

Comment: i don't know blade enabled or not. how to check its enabled or not

Comment: your view file should have blade in his name

Comment: hmm yes madalin my view file with .blade.php extention

Comment: is your ajax even triggering,do you have errors in the console?

Comment: No its return url like `http://localhost/editorlara4/public/posts/<?php echo URL::action{{PostsController@index}} ?>`

Comment: No madalin its return `http://localhost/editorlara4/public/posts/<?php echo URL::action('PostsController@index'); ?>`

Comment: what do you mean by return,does your page redirect right after you submit the form ?

Comment: no madalin its not redirect to PostsController@index

Comment: the code provided by me should work,how do you trigger the ajax?